# Error in references

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I am not sure why there is an error in the references. `OxyPlot.Wpf.LineSeries` to `OxyPlot.Series.Series` The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection.Add(OxyPlot.Axes.Axis)` has some invalid arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Wpf;
using OxyPlot.Axes;

namespace points
{
   public class PsdTest
    {
       public static PlotModel Filteringinvalidpoints()
       {
           var plotModel1 = new PlotModel();
           plotModel1.Title = "Filtering invalid points";
           var linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis();
           linearAxis1.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
           linearAxis1.Title = "X-axis";
           plotModel1.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);
           var linearAxis2 = new LinearAxis();
           linearAxis2.Title = "Y-axis";
           plotModel1.Axes.Add(linearAxis2);
           var lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();
           lineSeries1.Title = "NaN";
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NaN, double.NaN));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 0));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 10));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NaN, 20));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 10));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 0));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.5, double.NaN));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 0));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6, 10));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NaN, double.NaN));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(7, 0));
           lineSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NaN, double.NaN));
           plotModel1.Series.Add(lineSeries1);
           var lineSeries2 = new LineSeries();
           lineSeries2.Title = "PositiveInfinity";
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 11));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.PositiveInfinity, 20));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 11));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 1));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.5, double.PositiveInfinity));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 1));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6, 11));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(7, 1));
           lineSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
           plotModel1.Series.Add(lineSeries2);
           var lineSeries3 = new LineSeries();
           lineSeries3.Title = "NegativeInfinity";
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NegativeInfinity, double.NegativeInfinity));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 12));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NegativeInfinity, 20));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 12));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 2));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.5, double.NegativeInfinity));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 2));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6, 12));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NegativeInfinity, double.NegativeInfinity));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(7, 2));
           lineSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.NegativeInfinity, double.NegativeInfinity));
           plotModel1.Series.Add(lineSeries3);
           return plotModel1;
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into some issues with different namespaces. I can't say I entirely understand what you're attempting, so this may not give you the desired result, but I was able to get your code to compile using the following namespaces (having installed OxyPlot.Wpf via nuget):

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;
```

It may be the case that this doesn't help you, if it turns out you're after some specific behaviour found in the `OxyPlot.Wpf` namespace.